# Wordpress theme customization - hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woothemes

I buy a theme called "OSWAD THEME MARKET" from CodeCanyon and i create already a child theme. I want a menu in a hook. For now it is working but every theme update it replace my menu.

/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/functions/main.php

```
<div class="header-top hidden-xs <?php echo $version; ?>">

            <div class="header-top-container container">

                <?php if($version != 'v5'): ?>
                    <div class="left-header-top-content">
                        <?php if($smof_data['wd_text_shipping'] !==""): ?>
                            <div class="shipping-text"><?php echo $smof_data['wd_text_shipping'] ?></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if($smof_data['wd_phone'] !==""): ?>
                            <div class="phone-text"><?php _e('Phone: ', 'wpdance'); echo $smof_data['wd_phone'] ?></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if($smof_data['wd_hotline'] !=="" ): ?>
                            <div class="hotline-text"><?php _e('HotLine: ', 'wpdance'); echo $smof_data['wd_hotline'] ?></div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
```

For now i replace the div class "shipping-text" with this:

```
<div class="shipping-text">
<?php echo  wp_nav_menu( array(
'theme_location' => 'header-menu','container' => false, 'echo'
=> false,'items_wrap' => '%3$s','depth' => 0, ) ); ?></div>
```

How can i do that in functions.php? How can i override this hook with my menu?
And that my menu not disappear after theme update?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you update it in main theme direcory or in child theme directory?

Comment: update in the main theme directory

Comment: @webvision every theme has its own internals, I suggest you ask the theme author about your situation, he might give your correct hook and if not available then you can request for him to make it filterable/pluggable function so by the next upgrade by him, you will have correct filter/hook/or pluggable function to overwrite parent theme's code via your child theme without editing in the parent theme.